# calling function inside or outside filter

Tags: performance, scala, optimization

Let's say I have the following 2 functionally equivalent code snippets that return a list of strings that have their reversal also in the list:

```
var a = Array("abc", "bca", "abc", "aba", "cba")
a.filter(x => a.toSet(x.reverse)).distinct
```

and

```
var a = Array("abc", "bca", "abc", "aba", "cba")
var aSet = a.toSet  // notice that toSet is called outside filter
a.filter(x => aSet(x.reverse)).distinct
```

I'm wondering if there is a difference in the time complexity between these snippets, since in the first snippet I call `.toSet` for every element in `a`, whereas in the second snippet I call it only at the beginning. However, that being said, something tells me that the compiler might optimize the first call, yielding the 2 snippets equivalent in time complexity.

If the latter is true, could you please refer me to some relevant literature?

Thank you.

Comment: You could try the -print option on the scalac command to compare the generated Java code. You could also put in some timings and run the code a few thousand times to empirically check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, lets put it to the test (using Scalameter):

```
import org.scalameter.{Gen, PerformanceTest}
import org.scalatest._

import scala.collection.mutable

class SOPerformance extends PerformanceTest.Quickbenchmark {
  val gen = Gen.unit("unit")
    @inline def fn = {
        var a = Array("abc", "bca", "abc", "aba", "cba")
    a.filter(x => a.toSet(x.reverse)).distinct
    }
    @inline def fn2 = {
        var a = Array("abc", "bca", "abc", "aba", "cba")
        var aSet = a.toSet  // notice that toSet is called outside filter
        a.filter(x => aSet(x.reverse)).distinct
    }

  performance of "Range" in {
    measure method "fn" in {
      using(gen) in { gen ⇒
        fn
      }
    }
    measure method "fn2" in {
      using(gen) in { gen ⇒
        fn2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which shows that `fn` runs on average in 0.005674 millis and `fn2` runs on average in `0.003903` millis.

Now lets make this array a bit larger!

```
import org.scalameter.{Gen, PerformanceTest}
import org.scalatest._

import scala.collection.mutable

class SOPerformance extends PerformanceTest.Quickbenchmark {
  var a = (1 to 1000).map(_.toString).toArray

  val gen = Gen.unit("unit")

    @inline def fn = {
        a.filter(x => a.toSet(x.reverse)).distinct
    }
    @inline def fn2 = {
        var aSet = a.toSet  // notice that toSet is called outside filter
        a.filter(x => aSet(x.reverse)).distinct
    }

  performance of "Range" in {
    measure method "fn" in {
      using(gen) in { gen ⇒
        fn
      }
    }
    measure method "fn2" in {
      using(gen) in { gen ⇒
        fn2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This shows the true killer. `fn` takes on average 158.241861 ms, whereas `fn2` takes 0.353472 ms! Why? Because creating collections is really expensive! Especially sets, which require making a new HashSet, requires garbage collections and much more.